# How to pass model from view to javascript in asp.net MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to asp.net MVC4, please be patient.

I have a controller which returns ActionResult with a model.
I can use this model through Razor but I'd like to use it in JavaScript.
this what I've tried to do according to some answers on the internet:

```
@{
var property = Model;
}
var prop = @(property);
var data= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(prop ));
```

But it's not working.
What do I need to do in order to pass my model to JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.net mvc passing a C# object to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145716/asp-net-mvc-passing-a-c-sharp-object-to-javascript)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use

```
 <script>
     var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
 </script>
```

Problem with Your Code

```
@{
var property = Model; 
}
var prop = @(property); //Here model is not properly encoded
var data= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(prop )); //You are passing Javascript variable
```