# How to pass MVC model from view to JS function?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

How I can pass an object of the model from view to controller using JS function?

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="BulkUpdate(@Model)">Bulk Update</button>
        </div>

 function BulkUpdate()
    {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
```

Comment: Try: `BulkUpdate('@Model')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp.net mvc passing a C# object to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145716/asp-net-mvc-passing-a-c-sharp-object-to-javascript)

Comment: What about write hidden objects on view to use them on js?

Comment: Your model is C# object (server side)and your script will run at client side. How can you access the c# object at client side? Please, elaborate about your requirement so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ajax` to hit your controller method.
*see the example:*

**JS**

```
function BulkUpdate()
{
   var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(youModel))
   $.ajax({
       type: 'post', //GET
       url: '@Url.Action("Send", "Home")',
       data: JSON.stringify({ contact: model }),
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (data) {
           alert(data);
       }
   });

}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Send(Send contact)
{
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: please let me know if you feel have confusion.

Comment: Thanks, Ajay Kumar I am working on it if I have any issue I will contact you thank you so much

Comment: bro can you please share your contact number?

Comment: i dont think its a good idea, but we can do a discussion chat separately using stackoverflow discussion chat. check it somewhere in your question page.

Comment: Bro there is no option for chat ??

Comment: goto https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=mine&sort=active  ,,,,and create room and add me.