# How to import Json from C# ASP.Net core to JavaScript:

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a code that I need to import a variable from C# to JavaScript.

Within JavaScript, the variable is of the Json type.

When I manually create the variable inside JavaScript, my function and graphics work perfectly, but when I tried to get data from a C# variable, it doesn't work, my variable is empty.

This variable works when I create inside JavaScript:

```
var providerChart = [{ date: "2020-07-27", value: 13 }, { date: "2020-07-28", value: 11 }, { date: "2020-07-29", value: 15 }, { date: "2020-07-30", value: 16 }, { date: "2020-07-31", value: 18 }, { date: "2020-08-01", value: 13 }, { date: "2020-08-02", value: 22 }, { date: "2020-08-03", value: 23 }, { date: "2020-08-04", value: 20 }, { date: "2020-08-05", value: 17 }, { date: "2020-08-06", value: 16 }];
```

When I try import from C#, it doesn't work

```
var providerChart = JSON.parse('<%=dash.DadosChart%>');
```

I used an `alert();` to manage if the data arrived.

This is my controller, responsible to send my information to HTML and I have tried to use to send to JS too.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ConsumeAPI consume = new ConsumeAPI();

    consume.ReceiveCookie();

    Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();

    //dash.DadosChart = new List<string[,]>();

    dash.QtdeAplicacoes = consume.ProjetosCadastrados("projects");
    dash.UltimaDataAplicacao = consume.ConvertDate(consume.UltimoProjeto("projects"));

    dash.QtdeProjetoAtivo = consume.ProjetosAtivos("projects", diasAtivo);
    dash.Atual = consume.ConvertDate(consume.UltimoUpdate);

    dash.QtdeUsuarioCadastrado = consume.UsuariosRegistrados("authEntities");
    dash.UltimaDataUsuario = consume.ConvertDate(DateTime.Today);

    dash.PercentualProjetoCritico = (float)MathF.Round(consume.PercProjetoCritico("projectVersions"), 2);
    dash.BarraPercentualProjetoCritico = (float)MathF.Round(dash.PercentualProjetoCritico, 0);
    dash.PercentualProjetoRemediacao = (float)MathF.Round(consume.PercProjetoRemedicao(), 2);
    dash.BarraPercentualProjetoRemediacao = (float)MathF.Round(dash.PercentualProjetoRemediacao, 0);
    dash.PercentualVulnerabilidadeRemediada = (float)MathF.Round(consume.PercVulnRemediada(), 2);
    dash.BarraPercentualVulnerabilidadeRemediada = (float)MathF.Round(dash.PercentualVulnerabilidadeRemediada, 0);
    dash.PercentualProjetoPausado = (float)MathF.Round(consume.PercProjetoPausado(), 2);
    dash.BarraPercentualProjetoPausado = (float)MathF.Round(dash.PercentualProjetoPausado, 0);
    dash.DadosChart = "[";
    for(int i = 0; i < consume.apps.Count; i++)
    {
        bool isFirst = true;
        string myDate = consume.apps[i].Criado.Year.ToString() + "/" + consume.apps[i].Criado.Month.ToString() + "/" + consume.apps[i].Criado.Day.ToString(); 
        int vulnTotal = (consume.vulnApps[i].TotalAlta + consume.vulnApps[i].TotalBaixa + consume.vulnApps[i].TotalCritica + consume.vulnApps[i].TotalMedia);
        if(isFirst){
            dash.DadosChart += "{date: " + myDate + ", value: " + vulnTotal + "}";
            isFirst = false;
        }else
        {
            dash.DadosChart += ",{date: " + myDate + ", value: " + vulnTotal + "}";
        }
        //int vulnTotal = (consume.vulnApps[i].TotalAlta + consume.vulnApps[i].TotalBaixa + consume.vulnApps[i].TotalCritica + consume.vulnApps[i].TotalMedia);
        //string[,] dado = { { "date", "value" }, { consume.apps[i].Criado.ToString(), vulnTotal.ToString() } };
        //dash.DadosChart.Add(dado);
    }
    dash.DadosChart += "]";

    //dash.MyDataChart = JObject.Parse(dash.DadosChart);
    

    return View(dash);
}
```

PS.: I have used ASP.Net Core 3.1

Comment: In JavaScript, there is no Json type. There is string, which is typically how JSON is transmitted (and the reason for the naming of the `JSON.stringify` method), and there is Object (or Array, or one of the other more specific types), which are stringified for transmission or parsed from a JSON string (via `JSON.parse`).

Comment: First `[{ date:..` is not Json but javascript object [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/). Json has double quote around string "_A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes,_" [ref](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Comment: The way to get data from a C# type to JavaScript is to serialize it as JSON; So `var providerChart = JSON.parse('<%=JsonConvert.Serialize(dash.DadosChart)%>');` if you have Newtonsoft.Json imported.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp.net mvc passing a C# object to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145716/asp-net-mvc-passing-a-c-sharp-object-to-javascript)

Comment: Or to simplify, Heretic's suggestion, just output it into the JS as if it was a hard-coded literal to begin with, then you don't need to parse it, e.g. `var providerChart = <%=JsonConvert.Serialize(dash.DadosChart)%>;` (This is ok because JSON syntax is a subset of JS object literal syntax.)

Comment: @ADyson I have tried this before. I've thoght that error could be because I've used MVC model, so this .js is a individual arqchive and doesn't reconize my Newtonsoft.Json library.

Comment: More precisely, I think you mean it doesn't execute the C# code in he `<%` brackets. Yeah this code as shown would need to be in a cshtml view file. Probably you need to run that in a view, and structure your .js code in such a way that there is a function your view's JS can call which passes the data to it, so it can then draw the chart. That way you can trigger the code from the view, and have the necessary data available. Either that or you could make the JS make an AJAX call to fetch the JSON directly from a separate action method on the server. It's up to you.

Comment: @ADyson, you are corretly. I'm trying today to incluse the JS inside the cshtml and call the data via ViewBag. At the moment, it hasn't worked yet, but I'll continue keep trying.