# MVC Action Method & Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, api

I have an view with simple script as such:

```
 <script type="txt/javascript">
   function DoSomething(param)
   {
     alert(param);
   }
 </script>
```

Is there anyway I can call that function with a value in a controller action method return result?

**Edit:**

I really am looking to create/register JavaScript classes with Entity Framework values.
If it cannot be done how can I create/register Javascript classes with EntityFramework values?

OK, here's the thing:
I already have a JS function something like this:

```
RegisterClasses(param1, param2)
   {
     ......
   }
```

I have seen it done elsewhere thru Fiddler but do not know how they do it.

How can I pass values to that JS function to create classes from values in EF?

Comment: In reality I am trying to register/create JavaScript classes with EF classes but did not want to complicate the question

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to add this to the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">DoSomething(@Model.Param)</script>
```

adding a `Param` property to that action view model.

For using EF classes, you can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsModel = { 
                     name: "@Model.Name",
                     age: @Model.Age
                  };
</script>
```

Also, yo can just convert any object to json following this answer: [Convert .Net object to JSON object in the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502146/convert-net-object-to-json-object-in-the-view)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could JSON serialize your model to the view:

```
@model MyViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

    // now the model variable is a JSON representation of your
    // server side model that was passed by the controller action
    // to this view and you could manipulate it as a standard js variable


    // So assuming your model contains 2 properties Param1 and Param2 you
    // could pass them to your javascript method
    RegisterClasses(model.Param1, model.Param2);

</script>
```