# Is JSON.NET's caching strategy messing with my development cycle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, json.net

I'm trying to add a field to an existing datacontract in our system. (EF code first, POCO's with attribute hell :P)

However, when serializing the contract to the razor view (to stuff into an Angular.js model) the serializer omits the new field. If I step through in debug mode, the `Model` object in the view contains the field, but after I use `JsonConverter.SerializeObject(Model)` the output model does not include the new field.

I have recycled the apppool, restarted the website and restarted IIS without resolution. I have also inspected the data flow with fiddler to avoid any caching issues on the browser side.

The following workaround does actually work, so the property does exist on the model:

```
    var model = @Html.ToJson(Model);
    model.NewProperty = @Model.NewProperty;
    return {
        model: model
    };
```

...where `Html.ToJson(Model)` is an extension method that just calls `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)` and stuffs it into a `MvcHtmlString`.

Does anyone know what is going on? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557737/does-json-net-cache-types-serialization-information) there is some form of type information caching in json.net but it's hard to find any more information about it.

Comment: Are you checking this using an HTTP request?  My guess is your browser is caching the response.

Comment: Other parts of the page are updating fine, the model is inserted as part of the Razor render cycle, before the page is even sent to the browser.

Comment: Well, your browser and ASP.Net caches are where I would focus, not on JSON.Net's schema caching.

Comment: Maybe you have some pointers on where to start then. Especially with "ASP.Net caches".

Comment: Restart your ASP.Net server to clear that cache, and in your browser, check the box in your dev tools' "Network Tab" to "Disable Cache" to disable the client-side cache.  And verify the caching headers are behaving as desired in both the request and response.

Comment: Yes. Recycling and restarting were among the first things I tried. And fiddler tells me that the browser is not caching anything on it's side. Why are you so certain that the schema caching has nothing to do with it?

Comment: I never said I was certain it wasn't JSON.Net.  I consider this *far* more likely, and a more fruitful line of inquiry.  There is a difference.  I still think this.  I am very dubious this has anything to do with JSON.Net.

Comment: It's unlikely that Json.NET contract caching is causing the problem. The contract is runtime only and cached in a static variable, which persists only as long as the `AppDomain` in which it was instantiated.  Are you sure you marked your new member with `[DataMember]`?  Remember that data contract serialization is opt-in.

Comment: Well no... I didn't actually. I was not aware that datacontracts was handled specially in the serializer. I wasn't going to add the attribute until all the scaffolding was done with because I didn't want to create a migration right now. That's probably it, but I won't be able to test it until tomorrow. If you add it as an answer I'll give it to you.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm.  Is this set correctly?

Comment: @ChristianWattengård - if adding `[DataMember]` doesn't solve the problem, then I think we will need to see a [mcve] to help you.  In particular the source code for `Html.ToJson()` would be useful.  The version shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502797) uses `JavaScriptSerializer` not Json.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm trying to add a field to an existing datacontract in our system.*  Json.NET [supports data contracts](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm), and data contract serialization is [opt-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?view=netframework-4.7.1#remarks):

> Apply the DataContractAttribute attribute to types (classes, structures, or enumerations) that are used in serialization and deserialization operations by the DataContractSerializer...
>
> **You must also apply the DataMemberAttribute to any field, property, or event that holds values you want to serialize.** By applying the DataContractAttribute, you explicitly enable the DataContractSerializer to serialize and deserialize the data.

Thus if your model is marked with `[DataContract]`, then you need to mark your new member with [`[DataMember]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
[DataContract]
public class Model : SomeBaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string NewProperty;
}
```

Note that, even if your `Model` class is not marked with `[DataContract]`, Json.NET still requires that serializable members be marked with `[DataMember]` *as long as some base class of `Model` is marked with `[DataContract]`.*  For details see *[caliburn.micro serialization issue when implementing PropertyChangedBase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29200648/3744182)*.