# calling @Html.Action for JsonResult changes my response type in parent template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-type, jsonresult

I've got the following controller:

```
public class HelloController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View()
    }

    public ActionResult Hello()
    {
        return Json(new{ greeting = "hello, world!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Then, inside `Index.cshtml`:

```
...html stuffs
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("@Html.Action("Hello")");
</script>
```

What I'm finding is that, when going to this url in my browser, the response content type is `application/json; charset=utf-8` which causes the browser to render the html as a string instead of as... a web page.

What's the best way to get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason to this is that all `Html.Action` invocations are executed directly. Something like:

1. Index is called
2. View result is executed
3. Hello action is executed, set's ContextType
4. Index view result is returned
5. Browser displays the page

You got two options:

1. Break out the logic which generates "Hello world!" into a regular C# class and invoke it directly in the Index controller action
2. Load the Hello action through ajax and then display the `alert`.

#### Option 1

```
public class HelloController
{
    YourBusiness _yb;

    public HelloController(YourBusiness yb)
    {
        _yb = yb;
    } 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(yb.GenerateHello())
    }

    // used for everything but Index
    public ActionResult Hello()
    {
        return Json(new{ greeting = yb.GenerateHello() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

public class YourBusiness
{
    public string GenerateHello()
    {
        return "Hello wolrd!";
    }
}
```

#### Option 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('@Url.Action("Hello")', function(response) {
        alert(response.greeting);
    }
</script>
```

#### Side note

Internet Explorer is quite aggressive when it comes to caching. The JSON responses will be changed. I therefore recommend that you also specify no cache for the JSON action:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
public ActionResult Hello()
{
    return Json(new{ greeting = "hello, world!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I'm currently using option 2, but think I'll switch it out for something more like your first option to reduce my number of http requests. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Just use the overload of `Json(...)` to set the correct content type.

```
public class HelloController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View()
    }

    public ActionResult Hello()
    {
        return Json(new{ greeting = "hello, world!" }, "text/html", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather keep the content type as application/json so that the url can be used for purposes other than this particular use case

Answer (score 0):

If you return a JsonResult, via calling the Json() method, it won't return a web page. To return a page, you need to return a ViewResult, via calling the View method. Your method should have a corresponding view template

Check out [this](http://goo.gl/cIT6y) link or [this](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-views&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro) one