# ASP.NET MVC: View sometimes returned as application/json instead of text/html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, content-type

I have a view from which I call another view to render some json inside a script tag in my html:

```
public ActionResult App()
{
  return View();
}

public JsonResult SomeJsonData()
{
  // ... here goes the code that generates the model
  return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

inside my App.cshtml file I have something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var myJsonData = @Html.Action("SomeJsonData", "MyController");
</script>
```

The problem is that sometimes when I reload the page in the browser (using Chrome 20 right now) it shows all the markup, and if I go to the Network tab in the developer tools I can see that the Content-Type of the page request was of type "application/json". If I just reload the page then it loads correctly (the content type is "text/html" as it should be).

Any idea on why does this happen? or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When you return a `JsonResult` you are modifying the response Content-Type to `application/json`. So you first invoke the `App` controller action which returns a View and obviously sets the Content-Type to `text/html` and inside the returned view you call the `SomeJsonData` action which craps on the previous content type and modifies it to `application/json`. Of course the last one wins and that's what the user agent sees at the end of the day: `application/json`.

So, here's how to proceed:

```
public ActionResult App()
{
    // ... here goes the code that generates the model
    var model = ...

    return View(model);
}
```

and in your strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJsonData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I already have a model and the data I'm returning from that ActionMethod is not related to the model, I would have to add it to the ViewBag or something like that.

Comment: Oh no, may God forbid you to use ViewBag. Please, have mercy. Use a view model. If you already have a model returned from your `App` action then simply add a property to this **view model** (I strongly insist on the word **view model**, not to be confused with **model**) which will contain the required information. And if for some unexplainable reason you decide to go with ViewBag, I would like to simply say that this is crap, but it will work: `ViewBag.FooBar = someModel;` and inside the view `var myJsonData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.FooBar));`. But promise me you won't use ViewBag.

Comment: I know, I hate using ViewBag and try not to use it when I can avoid it. But there is some data that I need from certain views that just doesn't belong to that view model.

Comment: `But there is some data that I need from certain views that just doesn't belong to that view model.` => that's a contradictory sentence. Here's the thing: **if a view needs some data this data belongs to the view model**. Full stop. No further discussion possible. You might take whatever approach you want but if you don't use view models to pass data to your views, your approach will simply be wrong (according to my personal standards, which you should feel free to ignore :-), I just need to point it out for other people reading this post to avoid making the same mistake as you).

Comment: So, for example if I have a header across my site that uses an instance of my current user then you would add that user property to a base view model and make sure that every view in your site uses a model that inherits from that base one?

Comment: @willvv, probably not. You could use a child action that will take care of retrieving the user, building a view model and returning a partial view that will display the necessary information. Then you will simply include the child action in your Layout: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Comment: @DarinDimitrov hi, first of all happy new year :) I have a similar problem, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20845411/1480877 can you help me please, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just found another related question

[calling @Html.Action for JsonResult changes my response type in parent template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543953/calling-html-action-for-jsonresult-changes-my-response-type-in-parent-template)

I couldn't find anything before I posted.

The approach I'm gonna take is just changing the content type when returning the json data:

```
public JsonResult SomeJsonData(bool returnAsHtml = false)
{
  // ... here goes the code that generates the model
  return returnAsHtml ?Json(model, "text/html", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) : Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and on App.cshtml

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var myJsonData = @Html.Action("SomeJsonData", "MyController", new {returnAsHtml = true});
</script>
```

And I'm adding also a flag to allow calling the actionmethod from other places that are expecting an application/json response.

Answer (score 0):

Like other have said, the action that is returning JSON is changing the content-type of the response.

I was able to work around this by using a HtmlHelper to place the JSON into the page.  I am avoiding using the controller and action; my HtmlHelper is calling a static method.  This solution probably won't work in all cases and is kind of a hack, but you can avoid having to put the data into a bunch of view models this way.

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
   public static class JsonDataProviderHelper
   {
      public static MvcHtmlString JsonDataProvider(this HtmlHelper helper, JsonDataType jsonDataType)
      {
         switch (jsonDataType)
         {
            case JsonDataType.YARDSALE_MINI_CALENDAR:
               var yardsales = SalesEventCrud.GetByMonthForJavascript(null, MvcApplication.CurrentPortalId);
               return new MvcHtmlString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SalesEventCrud.GetByMonthForJavascript(null, MvcApplication.CurrentPortalId)));

            default:
               return new MvcHtmlString("");
         }
      }

      public enum JsonDataType
      {
         YARDSALE_MINI_CALENDAR
      }
   }
}
```

I am using json.net for serialization.  I have the `switch` statement because I plan to use this helper to return JSON for other situations also.

And in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      setupSmallSidebarCalendar(@Html.JsonDataProvider(JsonDataProviderHelper.JsonDataType.YARDSALE_MINI_CALENDAR));
   });
</script>
```

In the page, the data is written in straight JSON, so no other parsing / massaging of the data is needed.

Answer (score 0):

@Daran's found the cause - the ContentType gets overwritten with whatever was done *last*.  His solution should work, however if you still like the Action method pattern, you should be able to do something like the following and simply change the ContentType before you return.  It's still JSON data, but the content type plays nice with HTML views.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetJson(int someId, int foobar)
    {
        JsonResult result = CreateResult(someId, foobar);
        result.ContentType = "text/html";
        return result;
    }
```

The downside is that this is, well, a bit weird and/or unexpected behavior.  I doubt this will work if you called the endpoint via AJAX, for example.  But it looks like it would *almost* work and that would probably cause some confusion if it's in a shared codebase.  For that reason, if you do this, it may be worth naming the endpoint in such a way that it isn't misused.  You could even go so far as to create a new type of Result that is designed to work this way rather than use JsonResult.