# Submiting a Form is returning application/json instead of text/html

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, content-type

I have changed a Get submit using:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="@Url.Action(item.ListAction, item.ListController, new { ids = string.Join("-", item.Ids), categoryId = item.Id, search = (string)ViewBag.Search, location = (string)ViewBag.Location })">
```

To:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "homeCategoryForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.Hidden("ids")
    @Html.Hidden("categoryId")
    @Html.Hidden("search")
    @Html.Hidden("location")
}
```

Submiting it with JQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".innerelement", function (e)
{
    var elementId = e.target.id.split('_')[1];

    action = "/" + $("#controller_" + elementId).val() + "/" + $("#action_" + elementId).val();

    $("#homeCategoryForm").attr("action", action);
    $("#ids").val($("#ids_" + elementId).val());
    $("#categoryId").val($("#categoryId_" + elementId).val());
    $("#search").val($("#search_" + elementId).val());
    $("#location").val($("#location_" + elementId).val());

    $("#homeCategoryForm").submit();
});
```

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult GetAllByIds(string ids, int categoryId, string search, string location)
{
    AdGetAllByCategoryListViewModel model = new AdGetAllByCategoryListViewModel();

    model.Ads = Mapper.Map<IList<AdGetAllByCategoryDto>, IList<AdGetAllByCategoryViewModel>>(_adService.GetAllByIds(ids));

    model.Category = Mapper.Map<CategoryDto, CategoryViewModel>(_categoryService.GetById(categoryId));

    return View(MVC.Ad.Views.GetAllByCategory, model);
}
```

The problem is that the View using the Form Post method is producing a application/json View (Source) and not the text/html.

EDIT:

The view is been rendering from a PartialView, so maybe it's the problem?

I have tested with PartialView and the HTML of the View is rendered but not the all Layout View.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to see the controller action (the [HttpPost] action, if it's attributed that way).

Comment: it probably has nothing to do with your views. what is your controller code?

Comment: is there any other(overload) "GetAllByIds" in the code?

Comment: Thanks for your so fast answer, I have updated the question with the controller's code.

Comment: @JCLizard in this controller I don't have any other GetAllByIds Action.

Comment: its really hard to give you an answer like that. there needs to be the actual project for testing. at least out of my capabilities.

Comment: Are you sure it's reaching that action? Your `@using(Html.BeginForm` statement doesn't specify a controller or action.

Comment: @CAbbott yes, I debug all the code step by step, and it generates all the HTML code but in application/json mode and not in text/html. The code is all there in the submit result, but in like source View and not in rendered HTML

Comment: You seem to be using the View(IView, object) overload.  MVC.Ad.Views.GetAllByCategory will be responsible for rending of the View.  It's likely that piece of code is responsible for rending the content in json.  A quick way to check would just be to use the View(object) overload to make sure that works as intended.

Comment: @cgotberg Hi, thanks. I have also done that test with a View specific for that action and the result is the same. The only diference I have done is changing an anchor GET to a Form POST.

Comment: Did you add a new GetAllByIds in the controller when you changed for GET to POST or did you just change the existing one from GET to POST?  The Render method inside MVC.Ad.Views.GetAllByCategory is what's going to convert the object graph to some kind of content (json, html, whatever custom formatting).  Maybe you can add that to your post?

Comment: I had the GetAllByIds Action to the controller. The GetAllByCategory View remained the same. If I return a PartialView from the Action GetAllByIds, I get HTML but without the Layout Header and Footer, I only get the CSHTML page.

Comment: Let me see if I got that right: you are invoking the `GetAllByIds` controller action which returns the `MVC.Ad.Views.GetAllByCategory` view and instead of seeing the markup related to this view you are seeing some JSON in the browser?

Comment: Hi Darin, yes that's correct. I get application/json type and "/bundles/jquery?v=NPgYpEwC7OI85bfacd1A_xi18yFvEkZjugtwMlCsVAo1:1" has initiator. I'm making a deep debug and until now, a way to avoid this, is to remove a line that I have in the Layout: @{ Html.RenderAction(MVC.Comment.Create()); } it's a view that renders a coment form in the layout, but that don't give any error before the submit.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov FOUND IT!!!!! I'm going to post the solution. Thank you so much for your so fast availability to help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Problem:

In the Layout of the View I have a coment form:

```
<!-- Comments form container -->
<div class="comentsform">

    <!-- Comments form -->
    @{ Html.RenderAction(MVC.Comment.Create()); }

</div>
<!-- Comments form container closed -->
```

The Controller is:

```
public virtual PartialViewResult Create()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

The issue here is that I also have a JSON Action to send the comment by jQuery:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual JsonResult Create(CommentViewModel commentViewModel)
{
    CommentDto comentDto = Mapper.Map<CommentViewModel, CommentDto>(commentViewModel);

    _commentService.Create(comentDto);

    commentViewModel.Result = HeelpResources.CommentViewModelResultMsgOk;

    return Json(commentViewModel);
}
```

So it seems that, when the Layout is rendered coming from a Form POST action, it will search for all the [HttpPost] Actions of the Html.RenderAction presents in the Layout.

In this case, and because I have a Html.RenderAction with an [HttpPost] Action of type JsonResult, the all result View is converted in a JSON response.

So now, the only thing I have to do is to change the name of the JSON Action to public virtual JsonResult CreateSend for example, and Problem Solved!

Thanks again for the availability of all to help.

Comment: Doode.. U saved my day.. Thanks a lot. Just wanna add one more thing for other users reading this if you are posting any of your forms make sure you don't have any raw form (with content type JSON) in your submission cycle. For ex. if you have a page with 2 forms 1 form in pop up and other one on page. And if you have content type for pop up form as JSON then your on-page form will return result with content type JSON only.. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Rushikesh I'm glade that this problem helped you also. It was really complicated to figure out why this was happening. Thanks for your tips also. Regards.