# How to populate javascript variable with JSON from ViewBag?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, viewbag

I have this Index action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{  
    var repo = (YammerClient) TempData["Repo"];
    var msgCol = repo.GetMessages(); 

    ViewBag.User = repo.GetUserInfo();
    return View(msgCol.messages);
}
```

GetMessages returns a list of POCO messages and GetUserInfo returns a POCO with the info of the user (id, name, etc).

I want to fill a javascript variable with the JSON representation of the user info.

So I would want to do something like this in the view:

```
...
<script>
    var userInfo = "@ViewBag.User.ToJson()"
</script>
...
```

I know that doesn't work, but is there a way to do that? I want to avoid having to do an ajax request once the page is loaded just to get the user info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC: How to convert View Model into Json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365551/asp-net-mvc-how-to-convert-view-model-into-json-object)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In View you can do something like this

```
@{
        var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var userInfoJson = jss.Serialize(ViewBag.User);
}
```

in javascript you can use it as

```
<script>


    //use Json.parse to convert string to Json
    var userInfo = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(userInfoJson)');
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. I had to to a JSON.parse because it was getting it as a string: `var userInfo = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(userInfoJson)')`

Comment: you can skip the sever side serialization and just use `var userInfo = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.User))');`

Comment: I don't think you need to parse the json as a string. Just output `var userInfo = @Html.Raw(userInfoJson)`

Comment: @user3559349 Json.Encode throws error _Unexpected token_ however `var model = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));` worked good for me.

Comment: In the javascript:
without the single quote marks did it for me.

var userInfo = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(userInfoJson));

Answer (score 11):

Was using this solution for simple objects. But I had some problems getting an array to js objects  so I'll just leave what I did here.

C#

```
@{
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
  ViewBag.AvailableToday = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
}
```

js

```
var availableToday = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.AvailableToday)');
```

Comment: Hey i have been use this way but when i have property wich contains html or another json inside i get this error "Unexpected token t in JSON at position" i trying to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Client-Side Code:

This is an ajax call to a .Net MVC Controller:

```
var clientStuff;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetStuff", "ControllerName")',
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        clientStuff = data;
    },
    error: function(errorMsg) {
        alert(errorMsg);
    }
});
```

Server-Side Code:

CONTROLLER:

```
    public JsonResult GetStuff()
    {
        return Json(_manager.GetStuff(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

MANAGER:

```
    public IEnumerable<StuffViewModel> GetStuff()
    {
        return _unitofWork.GetStuff();
    }
```

UNIT OF WORK:

```
    public IEnumerable<StuffViewModel> GetStuff()
    {
        var ds = context.Database.SqlQuery<StuffViewModel>("[dbo].[GetStuff]");
        return ds;
    }
```

Unit of Work can be a query to a sproc (as I have done), a repository context, linq, etc.
I'm just calling a sproc here for simplicity, although it could be argued that the simplicity lies with Entity Framework and Linq.

Comment: For me this is the most elegant solution. Just one note that you want  clientStuff = JSON.parse(data); to actually store the object rather than the textual representation.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this line :

```
ViewBag.User = repo.GetUserInfo();
```

To

```
ViewBag.User = new HtmlString(repo.GetUserInfo());
```

You should add **using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;** or **using System.Web;** if HtmlString is not accessible.

Comment: Thanx Arash! That's the only way worked for me. I had to place "ld+json" on the page.

Comment: I am happy that it was helpful for you @Aviw. you are always welcome.

Comment: BTW, just to mention, I've used this in ASP.NET MVC, so it's available not only in Core