# Combine MVC .NET Razor with Javascript to build an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm passing a List from my controller to a view, where I want to be able to take the Model and loop through results in JQuery/Javascript. I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to do that.

My controller returns a list of colors. In the view, I converted the List to an array. I then pass it to my  where I'm trying to loop through it to build an array I can using in my JS.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var currentView = sessionStorage.getItem('lastView');
    var jsArr;
    for (i=0; i<@arr.Length; i++) {
        jsArr.push(@arr[i])
    }

    if (!currentView) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('lastView', 0);
        $("body").css("background-image", "url('/Images/Home/@arr[0].Location')");
    } else {

        sessionStorage.setItem('lastView', currentView++);
    }
})
</script>
```

There has to be an easy way of doing this...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var currentView = sessionStorage.getItem('lastView');
    var jsArr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(arr)) ;

    if (!currentView) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('lastView', 0);
        $("body").css("background-image", "url('/Images/Home/@Html.Raw(arr[0].Location)')");
    } else {

        sessionStorage.setItem('lastView', currentView++);
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thank's tvanfosson. I must be missing something. Your code won't work either. Within the <script> tags the var jsArr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(arr)) ";" semicolon flags a syntax error.

Comment: That's just a parsing error. Create a function called identity: `function identity(val) { return val; }` and do: `var jsArr = identity(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(arr)));` if you want to get rid of the syntax error.

Comment: As for TGH's answer, the quotes are missing around the razor code - `var jsArr ='@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(arr))';`

Comment: Thanks TGH! You were right. I forgot the quotes and that's what was throwing me off. It's all working great now.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead return json from the server. However if you want to do it in an html view I think something like this might work:

```
var jsonObj = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.arr))'

//the loop is unnecessary, but can be useful if you need additional processing
var myArray = [];
for (i=0; i<jsonObj.length; i++) {
        myArray.push(jsonObj[i])
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay THG. I tried something like that, but it doesn't play well within the <script> tags. I tried your code and replaced the arr you are encoding with my Model. Tying to use that within my JQuery block and it doesn't work. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: There are a few more ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365551/asp-net-mvc-how-to-convert-view-model-into-json-object

Comment: @TGH, I think you are missing quotes `var jsonObj = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to manually build a JSON or JS object with razor code, some very easy to use code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Users)
    {
    <text>
    UserData[UserData.length] = {
        "UserID": '@item.ID', "FullName": '@item.Name'
    };
    </text>
    }
```

I purposefully showed model property names being used and JSON property names being different to show an advantage of manually building the array.

Also, in this case you would be able to send a model through with multiple collections of data. Then just iterate through that collection (`@foreach (var item in Model.Users)`) with your Razor code to build your JSON or Javascript object array