# Is it possible to serialise a View Model and pass it to the controller without a form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, serialization

I am setting up a wizard control and was hoping to be able serialise and pass around a single view model with all the accumulated values between the various controllers using AJAX.

I have used `myForm.serialize()` with AJAX a number of times and was sure there would be some equivalent, something as simple as `myViewModel.serialize()` ...but it does not seem to be a thing?

Am I missing something obvious?

Please note this is NOT a duplicate of the half-dozen or so cases about serialising the form and sending it to the controller. I am explicitly interested in serialising the View Model independently of a form.

Comment: Maybe this question help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365551/asp-net-mvc-how-to-convert-view-model-into-json-object

Comment: Thanks @LucasSouza, definitely looks promising!