# use c# class object in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json

I want to use a object which is created in c# class in `javascript` . I know i can use json library to convert my server side object to `JSON` object so that it can be use in `javascript`.

I have downloaded the `Newtonsoft.Json` library for this . i have following `aspx.cs` page code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        product p = new product();
        p.ProductId = 1;
        p.productName = "t-shirt";

    }

    public class product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and for `aspx` page i am using following code for `javascript` to access that p object value .

```
    <%@ Import Namespace="Newtonsoft.Json" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript">

var jsobject = <%= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p) %>;

function myfunction (){ 
  //work with object
  alert('Hi');
}

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

when i try to build this its generate following exception

**`The name 'p' does not exist in the current context`**

i just want to use p id and name in my javascript code.

I have taken initially reference from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1503235/779158)

Comment: `p` is the name of the variable, which you're calling `jsobject` in your JS. You should be able to use `jsobject.productId` and `jsobject.productName` if I understood correctly how this library works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of your variable p is not right.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public product p;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p = new product();
        p.ProductId = 1;
        p.productName = "t-shirt";

    }

    public class product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Website finally runs thanks but now in console following error is coming .Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProductId' of null  . I understand its means p is null but don't have idea why its null ?

Comment: how does the resulting html look like?

Comment: Do you mean rendered page HTML ?

Comment: there is no json object in rendered html ?

Comment: i have made an sample project based upon your code. 
pre rendered it looks like:
<pre><code> <script>
        var jsobject = <%= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p) %>;
        alert(jsobject.productName);
        </script></pre></code>
And rendered:
<pre><code>  <script>
        var jsobject = {"ProductId":1,"productName":"t-shirt"};
        alert(jsobject.productName);
        </script>
</code></pre>

Comment: rendered section is not coming in my html rendered as coming in your case productId:1 and ProductName:t-shirt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30388/discussion-between-rahularyansharma-and-raimond-kuipers)

Answer (score 1):

You can not access local variables of a function in scriptlets define a public property or data member.

```
public product p {get; set;}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    p = new product()
    p.ProductId = 1;
    p.productName = "t-shirt";
}
```